# How can we set oledb provider for 64 bit operating system

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to get oledb provider for jet 4.0 in my sql. I am using 64 bit version of windows.

I have created a linked server to access the access database and import that database to sql.

So, I have written one stored procedure to create a linked server there i mentioned provider as Microsoft oledb jet 4.0.

I got error like this in 64 bit

> 'OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.'

In 32 bit windows it is working fine. I installed microsoft oledb jet drivers. But in 64 bit It is not being installed.

Can u pls tell me the suggestion to get provider oledb jet 4.0 in Sql linked servers.

Comment: Try using `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` in your connection string  instead of `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`

Comment: Is this windows forms or ASP?

Comment: The same with Excel: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/distributed-queries-are-configured-to-run-in-single-threaded-apartment-mode

Comment: This is also not working I also checked this before

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use MS Access database, you need to install a database access engine. Check the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 Also consider the version of the Access you have installed on the host machine in your connection string.

Comment: I got error like this while connecting to linked server using ACE Engine 'Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ClientAc825".
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ClientAc825" returned message "Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.".'

Answer (score 0):

For me what works is to install the database driver from: 
The 2016 Access Redistributable
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
And then adjust my connection string for example:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=F:\SKS\SKSDatabase\Orders.mdb";
```